# Persistir uma entidade que é herdada

Tags: java, hibernate

Tenho uma entidade ***Pessoa*** que é herdada em outra entidade ***Administrador***. No banco eu já tenho dados na entidade ***Pessoa*** e quero associar uma ***Pessoa*** na entidade ***Administrador***. Como eu posso fazer isso?
Detalhes: Eu estou usando `hibernate`, e usando uma `class Dao` que herda `JpaRepository`

---

**Class: Pessoa**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Pessoa extends PersistableEntity<Long> { // Essa herança tem o Id, e os equals&hashCode

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String nome;
```

---

**Class: Administrador**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Administrador extends Pessoa {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Answer (score 2):

## Possível Solução

O código da pergunta funcionaria com alguns ajustes nas anotações. Você poderia considerar como se já houvessem dados da entidade `Administrador`. Se você recuperar um `Administrador` que não tenha um registro na respectiva tabela, mas seja uma `Pessoa` válida, o Hibernate provavelmente vai gerar um `LEFT OUTER JOIN` e recuperar os dados existentes ignorando os demais. Então, um `update` incluiria os dados na tabela da subclasse.

*Note que esta é uma suposição. Podem haver detalhes que impeçam esta abordagem.*

## Problemas

Por outro lado, embora possa fazer sentido no contexto da sua aplicação um `Administrador` ser uma `Pessoa`, essa modelagem traz problemas para a implementação. Aliás, será que a `Pessoa` não deveria ser um `Administrador`?

De qualquer forma, a [herança como é implementada no Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html) não é tão flexível a ponto de refletir qualquer hierarquia que criamos em classes. Pelo contrário, os métodos são bem limitados.

Um dos exemplos mais comuns é a questão do polimorfismo. Por exemplo, o Hibernate até permite algum tipo de polimorfismo, mas em geral, as estratégias de herança comuns como *table per subclass* somente permitem que você lide com um conjunto limitado de subclasses e não diretamente com as superclasses.

Faz sentido usar herança em Hibernate quando uma superclasse tem várias possíveis subclasses e não apenas uma. Nesse caso, é preciso anotar a superclasse com `@DiscriminatorColumn` para informar ao Hibernate uma coluna que define qual tipo de subclasse cada registro deve representar.

## Solução Ideal

No seu contexto, minha indicação seria não usar herança, mas um relacionamento `1:1` (um-para-um) entre `Pessoa` e `Administrador`. Mais especificamente, a classe `Administrador` poderia ter um atributo do tipo `Pessoa`. Imagino que a tabela `Administrador` já tenha uma *Foreign Key* para `Pessoa`, não é?

Eu sei que pode soar um pouco estranho, mas faz sentido se você pensar em termos de:

- Não alterar o código existente na classe `Pessoa`
- Evitar complexidade desnecessária no mapeamento com o Hibernate
- Não impactar funcionalidades que usam a classe `Pessoa`, mas que não tem nenhuma dependência com a classe `Administrador`
- Simplesmente é mais simples

Comment: Realmente, amigo faz todo sentido essa sua resposta bem mais facil fazer esse relacionamento 1 para 1